# ttyACM0 and sdb created from one physical USB device

Tags: linux, usb-drive, block-device

I have a USB device based around the Nordic Semiconductors nRF51 SoC. Once I plug it into my Ubuntu machine it triggers the creation of both `/dev/ttyACM1` and `/dev/sdb`. So far, I've perceived the `/dev/ttyACM1` as a UART serial device. I don't know what to make of this. There are no custom udev rules added.

Output of `lsusb -v`:

```
Bus 002 Device 022: ID 1366:1015 SEGGER 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 ?
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1366 SEGGER
  idProduct          0x1015 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 SEGGER
  iProduct                2 J-Link
  iSerial                 3 000680636054
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          121
    bNumInterfaces          4
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 Configuration
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass          2 Communications
      bFunctionSubClass       0 
      bFunctionProtocol       0 
      iFunction               0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Abstract (modem)
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
      iInterface              5 CDC ACM
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC Call Management:
        bmCapabilities       0x03
          call management
          use DataInterface
        bDataInterface          1
      CDC ACM:
        bmCapabilities       0x06
          sends break
          line coding and serial state
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        0
        bSlaveInterface         1 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x87  EP 7 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               8
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              6 CDC DATA
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x04  EP 4 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              7 J-Link
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        3
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              8 MSD
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x85  EP 5 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x06  EP 6 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 ?
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

What is the mechanism that would trigger a `ttyACM1` to be recognized as both `ttyACM1` and `/dev/sdb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usb devices can have multiple interfaces (eg a speaker with control buttons). Each interface is independent though there can be a descriptor saying they should work in association. If the interface uses a device class supported by Linux then a class driver will be used to make it available. There are class drivers for *Communications Device Class* and *Mass Storage*. In your case perhaps the serial port is for sending commands, and the mass storage is for writing the flash memory. Look at the output of `lsusb -v` for your device for details on the interfaces.

Comment: Updated with output of `lsusb -v`. The interfaces you're referring to are `Interface Descriptor`? There seems to be 4 of them. So the assumption is that only 2 of them are recognized by Linux and they are the ones being loaded as `ttyACM0` and `/dev/sdb`?

Comment: yes, I'm not sure of the details, but interface 0 is class 2, subclass 2, protocol 1 which seems to be matched by the common usb/class/cdc-acm.ko driver module, along with interface 1 which actually does data transfer. The two are combined by the *Interface Association* in front of them. Interface 2 is vendor specific with no driver (unless the vendor/device id match one). Interface 3 is class 8, subclass 6, protocol 80 for mass storage driver usb-storage.ko

Comment: `lsusb -t` should show you which driver is being used for a device.